# Script for finding undefended pieces

Tags: programming, cql

I am looking for a script/code/CQL that searches for undefended pieces in  a given position. I know that is possible to do it in the python chess library, but that is too complicated for me.

Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't something like the folowing be good enough? (* stands for however you check that `potentialDefendingPiece`can move to `piece`'s square)

```
for (piece in WhitePieces) {
  defended = false;
  for (potentialDefendingPiece in WhitePieces) {
    if(*)
     defended = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Chess Query Language" for coding this, as it will be quicker to work with and easier to understand.